# Spring 5 and escaping in Springs freemarker macros

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

After updating to Spring 5 all output from Spring freemarker macros are escaped. In <@spring.message> the message is escaped and in <@spring.formRadioButtons> the separator attribute is escaped f.x. "<br/>".

Config:

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer config = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    config.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/templates/ftl/");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("template_update_delay", getFreemarkerUpdateDelay());
    props.put("template_exception_handler", getFreemarkerExceptionHandler());
    props.put("url_escaping_charset", WebConstants.CHAR_SET_UTF_8);
    config.setFreemarkerSettings(props);
    config.setDefaultEncoding(WebConstants.CHAR_SET_UTF_8);
    return config;
}
```

We use Freemarker 2.3.28 and Spring 5.0.7.RELEASE

TIA for any ideas on how to turn off escaping of the output from the macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/spring.ftl, it starts with `<#ftl output_format="HTML" ...>`, so that particular template has activated HTML auto-escaping for itself, which is stronger than the `outputFormat` `Configuration` setting. Since `MessageSource.getMessage` can only return `String` (and thus not a `TemplateMarkupOutputModel`, which is not auto-escaped by FreeMarker), it seems to me that the maintainers has made a serious oversight here. They have broken backward compatibility very much (assuming it indeed didn't escape in Spring 4), but worse, I don't see how they wanted to support not escaping. There's no such variation of `spring.message` or anything. (And it yet again strikes back that `spring.message` isn't a function, because then you could apply `?noesc` on it.) So you should report it to them.

Update: Earlier I have recommended disabling auto-escaping on `spring.ftl` via `template_configurations` and `auto_escaping_policy`, but it turns out that's wrong, since some macros did escaping in Spring 4 via `?html`, which they have removed when switching to auto-escaping. So then those won't escape, which is wrong again...

Comment: The corresponding Spring ticket that causes this change:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14740

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. So now it behaves similarly as if they had `?html` in all interpolation in Spring 4, but they had not, like `#macro message` didn't have it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9b2023111d3c6601a482587a19f09a8a9976c1ee/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/spring.ftl. They had to write `${someExpression?noesc}` on those places when adding the `#ftl output_format='HTML'` header.

Comment: I have also removed my earlier idea of using `auto_escaping_policy`... see update why.

Comment: Thank you for all input on this thread! I have now created an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16951.

Comment: @KajHejer Great, thanks! Though it's certainly not a "Minor" issue in the scope of using `spring.ftl`. (BTW, I'm not sure if they have used the opportunity (5.0) to increase the `incompatible_improvements` setting, but if not, I would recommend to set it to `2.3.28`.)

Comment: @ddekany Thank YOU! :) What would be the best way to offer a solution to turn of escaping for selected parameters? Do you have a suggestion to a list of changes that should be made to spring.ftl? The more concrete we are in our suggestion to changes in SPR-16951, the better the solution will be :)

Comment: It's simple. Where they had `${foo}` that doesn't contain `?html` in Spring 4, now they should have `${foo?noesc}`. Of course, where they had `${foo?html}` in Spring 4, the `${foo}` should say in Spring 5.

Comment: @ddekany Thank you! :)